# Kruskal Wallis on difference scores?

Tags: repeated-measures, nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test, pre-post-comparison

I'm wondering whether it's possible to do a Kruskal-Wallis test on difference scores, since I can't seem to find an example of this online. I think it would make sense conceptually, but I would like to confirm if it makes sense statistically?

I'd like to know whether groups differ on the dependent variable across time. I searched for a nonparametric equivalent for a mixed-measures ANOVA, but did not seem to find something suitable.

Info about the dataset:

- small sample (9 participants)
- residuals not normally distributed
- 1 between subjects factor with 3 levels (interventions)
- 1 within subjects factor with 2 levels (time; pre- and post-measurement)
- dependent variable=continuous (bin weight)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't use the Kruskal Wallis test on values that represent the difference in scores. But I can't say I have a reference that uses this approach.

However, it is often advantageous to construct a model that retains the original scores for both the "*pre-*" and "*post-*" times.  Plotting the e.g. means or medians for the interaction of *Time* and *Intervention* may give a better sense of the data for the reader (and analyst).  If you use good software, and can fit an appropriate model, you will often have access to an *emmeans* option or function that will report the predicted values from the model for e.g. the e.m. means for the interaction, often with confidence intervals for these values.  Plotting all this conveys a lot of information.

If you want to use a nonparametric approach, you might look at aligned ranks transformation anova. The implementation in R (*ARTool* package) is easy to use and allows for random effects (which can take into account the repeated measures nature of the design).

But likely there is another type of model (such as a ***generalized*** linear model) that may work for your situation.

[image]